# Flutter: How to write campaign (UTM) parameters in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

How do I write campaign parameters in Flutter? I have push notification enabled. So when a user comes to my app from notification I want to write some UTM information to google analytics e.g source, medium, campaign

I am using "usage 3.4.1" plugin for Flutter but I don't see any option/API to write UTM parameters to GA

Need some help on how to accomplish this...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You track the UTM parameters with the [logCampaignDetails](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_analytics/latest/firebase_analytics/FirebaseAnalytics/logCampaignDetails.html) method

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions(flavor).currentPlatform);

analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

analytics?.logCampaignDetails(
          source: "utm_source", medium: "utm_medium", campaign: "utm_campaign"); // Your information here
```